# I'm having a research. A comparison of two laptops. Which is better?

Tags: windows, intel, nvidia, ryzen

I am wondering price wise which is better?

An **AMD Ryzen 7 5600h (HP VICTUS) with 8gb ddr5 48mhz NVIDIA RTX 3050 4GB ** or an **intel core i5 11400H with a 16gb ddr4 32 mhz NVIDIA RTX 3050Ti 4GB?** (Lenovo Legion 5)

**This is For Virtual Assistant work, photo editing, browsing, a little bit of games and a little bit of coding**

Is an 8gb ddr5 sufficient or a 16gb ddr4 as well as the processor?

This is a laptop comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If the specs are really like listed, they are both a total scam since those RAM configs are impossible :) I am gonna assume the ram speeds are multiplied by 100 for this answer then.

The first laptop is way better, just because you generally need more than 8GB of ram to run your VMs and IDEs. Also for browsing, you can't have much more than 50 chrome tabs open (with KDE). For photo editing and Minecraft it may be enough if you run Linux, but for other games or if you want to run Windows, 16GB is better.

Assuming all other things are the same (cooling, screen, keyboard, ...) the second one is clearly better, just because it has enough RAM.

(btw thats also why I don't like macbooks, you pay like more than a thousand euros for a laptop with 8GB ram and 256GB storage. And the OS is pretty locked down)

Comment: I have edited the question because I forgot to add something @Irsu85. The second is a Lenovo Legion 5. Both are supposed to be running Windows 10 and have 512 gb nvme ssd

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it does not change my answer